# Background image and also background color in TableLayout

Tags: android, background, tablelayout

I'm developing an Android app and I want to create a TableLayout with a white background and  a background image aligned at the top left, because is a 'bend effect'.

This is the top left image:

[image: bend effect]

I defined the TableLayout like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white" >
```

But I don't know how to put the image at the top left, or if background images are compatible with background colors or if there is a better way to do this thing...

Comment: You can only have 1 background. Choose between a color, an image or a drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to define where the image will go is to use an Imageview inside that layout. You can define placement of the image by using android:gravity

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the bend effect using `ImageView` where the White color will be background and the image will be set as `src` as below...

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I insert an ImageView inside the TableRow

```
<!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            >
    <!-- top left bend -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_left_corner_bend"
        android:contentDescription="@string/email"
    />
    <!-- top left bend -->
    </TableRow>
```

And works ok. Thanks.